# bubble sort function in C - undefined symbols error

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to write a simple program to bubble sort an array of integers. I'm getting the error:

```
Segmentation Fault
```

I know this normally has to do with linking with the correct library but I'm not sure what one I'm missing?

Here's my program:

```
 //Bubble Sort program

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubblesort(int list[], int N);



//To do: write a function to allocate an array of size N. N will be input by the user

//TODO:Write a function allocatearray()
int *allocatearray(int N){
  int *array;                  
  array = malloc(N * sizeof(int));    //making an array of changeable size
  return array;
}

int main()  {
  int *array;
  int n, i, d, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //scanf("%d", &array[i]); 
      scanf("%d", &array[i]);  
      bubblesort(array, n);

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");
  for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
     printf("%d\n", array[i]);
     }

  return 0;
}

//TODO:Write a function bubblesort()
void bubblesort(int list[], int N) {
  int i, d, t;
  for (i = 0 ; i < (N - 1); i++) {        //array of entered integers
    for (d = 0 ; d < (N - i - 1); d++) {  //d array is one smaller than c
        if (list[d] > list[d+1]) {            //if value "d" is greater than "d + 1"
        /* Bubble swap */
        t = list[d];                     //create new long variable t equal to value of list[d]
        list[d] = list[d+1];             //update d value to d + 1 value
        list[d+1] = t;                   //
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Erm.. I didn't read your program. But did you notice that you define a function called `bubblesort` but call a function called `bubble_sort`? Also, I would declare the function before `main`.

Comment: Besides the bubblesort/bubble_sort issue, you don't appear to be allocating space for array before using it.

Comment: Phil... this is the error I'm getting now. I don't really understand how to allocate the space... i guess I assumed I was doing that by using the allocatearray function?

Answer (score 0):

You call function `bubble_sort()` while it is actually named `bubblesort()`. You also have to create a definition before main function, for example add:

```
void bubblesort(int list[], int N)
```

right below `int *allocatearray(int N)` definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use function `bubble_sort` in your `main` function but it is not declared anywhere, thus compiler complains it cannot find this method.

Even if this is only a typo mistake, calling `bubblesort` won't work too because `main` function is located upper `bubblesort`, thus compiler will complain that it does not know any method named `bubblesort`. You need either to put the `bubblesort` method before the `main` one, or add a prototype line before your `main`:

```
//declare the signature of the method, the implementation is found below.
void bubblesort(int list[], int N);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use your function bubblesort in main without declaring it at the top of your c source file.

You have two ways to follow:

1. Cut and paste bubble sort function to the top:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   //To do: write a function to allocate an array of size N. N will be input by the user

   //TODO:Write a function allocatearray()
   int *allocatearray(int N){
     int *array;                  
     array = malloc(N * sizeof(int));    //making an array of changeable size
     return array;
   }

   void bubblesort(int list[], int N) {
   int i, d, t;
   for (i = 0 ; i < (N - 1); i++) {      
   //AND ON...

   int main()  {
   // ...
   }
   ```
2. Just add function definition at the top:

   ```
   void bubblesort(int list[], int N);
   ```

   Right below #includes.

Comment: Ok now it's compiling but I'm getting a segmentation fault error. I know these are because I didn't allocate that memory, but I thought that was the point of using the dynamic array?

Comment: @user3306583: There's no such thing like an array of changeable size. In C you can't define an array without defining how many "sets of bytes" must be allocated in your stack memory.
You can solve this in three ways:
 1. Asking the user for the number of elements he wants to add, and allocating an array of x elements (where x is the integer the user typed)
 2. Pre-allocate a, let's say, 1000 elements array so that you "cover" yourself from "no more space in array" error.
 3. Learn how to create a list. It's a bit tougher but definitely more powerful.

Comment: Isn't this the purpose of creating a dynamic array though?